# Mongoose: How can I generate a valid mongoose.Types.ObjectId?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am unit testing some code that has a dependency on Mongoose models. I'd like to verify that a function has been passed a valid ObjectId as an argument. I've read that new ObjectId objects can be created using:

```
 var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
```

However the following will always return false:

```
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id) //false
```

Why is this? Is it because I'm creating a new ObjectId instance without a key? Looking through the Mongoose source I can see that mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid is actually defined in the native mongo module. I will continue to dig into the driver but if someone can tell me off hand why the above behavior is occurring I would appreciate the time savings :p

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`isValid` is a [poorly documented](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#ObjectID.isValid) method of the BSON `ObjectID` class in the native driver.

If you look at [the source](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/master/lib/bson/objectid.js#L241) for that method, you'll find that it's expecting a string to be passed in, so you'd need to call it as:

```
mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id.toString())
```

However, as @HMR points out in the comments, the implementation of `isValid` has the odd quirk of considering *any* 12-character string to be be valid. See [source](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/master/lib/bson/objectid.js#L241).

So unfortunately, it's probably better to implement the check yourself using an approach like:

```
if (id.toString().match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
  // It's a valid ObjectId
}
```

Comment: According to the code here: https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/master/lib/bson/objectid.js#L241 any string that is 12 characters long is a valid id. So those who use this utility function should do so with care. Already filed an issue: https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/issues